# how to change windows language in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, activexobject

i need change `windows language` from `EN` to `fa`(both of them are installed).i read some articles and  found it is not possible in asp.net and  must use `activex`. I create an activex and write this code in it's constructor:

```
   InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = 
InputLanguage.FromCulture(
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("Fa-IR"));
```

then add activex dll to my project and create object from it. but it doesn't change windows language. any idea for that?( `activex` run correct because my `messagebox` are shown in webpage)

```
update:
```

the language is changed to `fa` when `messagebox` is shown but again change to `en` when messagebox is closed

Comment: Take a look at UICulture and Culture. That should work out for you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to change the language on the client or on the server?

Comment: change on the client .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = 
InputLanguage.FromCulture(
new CultureInfo("Fa-IR"));
```